# How to show top comment in RecyclerView without scrolling down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore as a backend.I have a dialogue in my app, that pops up when I click the floating action bar button, where I can enter some text. I then submit the comment. It goes to the top of the `recyclerview`, which is what I want. However I have to scroll down to see the comment. How can I show the top comment without scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

Put the lines below when you submit the comment:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to scroll your RecyclerView to top programatically. Use this method in `onClick` after all stuff.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
```

Comment: my OnClick method is in a Dialog fragment. My recyclerview is in an activity. If the recyclerview is scrolled halfway down, it will jump to the top post when a post is submitted. My problem only occurs when the view is at the highest it can go...eg Index 0 at the highest it can go  in the view. Tried above solution ...same outcome

Comment: I did not get you, can you tell in other words?

Comment: I am sure, it is solvable. You have to clear me about your problem.

Comment: ok so I did as you said. My problem seems intermittent. The post always goes to the top. Sometimes I can see it without scrolling. however sometimes I have to scroll to see it

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(position);
      or this one
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

hope this helps you!!!